# Почему не идёт запись в файл?

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<File> vuhod = new ArrayList<>();
//Коллекция vuhod заполнена файлами
File res1 = new File("D:\\allFilesContent.txt"); 
//Файл res1 (который точно существует) для записи того, что мы считаем из каждого файла vuhod
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(res1));
for (int i = 0; i < vuhod.size(); i++)
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vuhod.get(i)));
    while (reader.ready())
    {
        writer.write(reader.readLine());
    }
    if (i == vuhod.size() - 1) {
    } else {
        writer.write('\r');
        writer.write('\n');
    }
```

Почему не заполняется файл, и что значат строки `writer.write('\r');` и `writer.write('\n');`?

Comment: `\r\n` - символ переноса строки в файловой системе Windows.

Comment: writer.write('\r');
writer.write('\n'); тоесть после этого в файле будет 2 переноса?

Comment: Нет. \r\n это единый символ и обозначает он один перенос.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запись в файл не идёт, так как вы не вызываете метод `flush` у `writer`.

`BufferedWriter` пишет данные в свой буфер (размер по умолчанию которого равен `8192` символам) и в выходной поток (`FileWriter`) отправляет данные из буфера только при его заполнении или при вызове `flush()` или `close()`.

Также стоит закрывать за собой потоки чтения и записи. Для это удобно использовать конструкцию [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Вызов метода `close` у `BufferedWriter`, кстати, приводит к отправке данных из буфера в выходной поток, так что в этом случае вызывать метод `flush` вручную не придётся.

В итоге код выглядит так:

```
List<File> vuhod = Arrays.asList(new File("in1.txt"), new File("in2.txt"));
File res1 = new File("out.txt");
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(res1)))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vuhod.size(); i++)
    {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vuhod.get(i))))
        {
            while (reader.ready())
            {
                writer.write(reader.readLine());
            }
            if (i < vuhod.size() - 1)
            {
                writer.write('\r');
                writer.write('\n');
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: исчерпывающий ответ, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

у меня работает так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = "E:\\MyProjects\\StackO\\questions\\634328";

    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    files.add(new File(path + "\\1.txt")) ;
    files.add(new File(path + "\\2.txt")) ;
    files.add(new File(path + "\\3.txt")) ;
    files.add(new File(path + "\\4.txt")) ;


BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path + "\\ConcatFile.txt"));

for(File file: files){
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
        writer.write(line);
    }
    reader.close();
}
writer.close();
}
```

Это если очень уж надо на чистом io

Comment: можно и на nio прост я с ним не оч)